# How to debug Webchat in iPhone Simulator

Tags: web-chat

I was facing an issue on Audio not playing in voice bot in iPhone (Mic works) alone and was trying to debug the same in iPhone simulator in Mac (since I don't have access to a real device). However, in the simulator, the [sample bot](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/03.speech/b.cognitive-speech-services-js/) doesn't seem to be working. Here is the screengrab:

[image]

How am I supposed to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test directly on an iPhone. Per the [iPhone Simulator docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1):

> #### Hardware Differences
>
> Though most of the functionality of devices can be simulated in Simulator, some hardware features must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2 are:

> - Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
> - **Audio and video input (camera and microphone) are unsupported.**